# How to filter requests in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

As I'm new to PHP previously i worked on JAVA, currently for my web application i'm using codeigniter. I want to configure a filter where i can filter every request to identify whether any harmful data is coming from user or not(same as java filter).

Comment: `what have you tried`?

Comment: In codeigniter this is done by `security_helper`, + you can set up in config.php some values like `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;` after all here is a quick link to `CI guide` http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/security.html

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter have Security and Input Class, Look:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/security.html and
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html

AFAIK, That's all you can get. CI is just a small (IMO) Framework. If you want more, you need to create your own by [creating library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html) and/or [extending the core](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html).